# Parse XML Data in Arduino

Tags: c, xml, http, parsing, arduino

I am trying to read XML data in Arduino from  a google spreadsheet published to the web using an HTTP GET request to the following link.

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/SpreadsheetID/5/public/basic?&range=D10
[image]
I receive the following reply along with some headers which I can observe on the serial port.

I want to parse the data written in bold format in the above reply. The data can be a real number and can be positive & negative. Please help me to find a way to parse this data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out this library?

https://web.archive.org/web/20160622041818/http://interactive-matter.eu/how-to/ajson-arduino-json-library/

You're better off converting your XML to JSON and giving that a go considering the memory availability on Arduino.

Otherwise if you really want to work with XML, then there's always these resources:

https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/XMLWriter

http://john.crouchley.com/blog/archives/454

Comment: The first link is no longer available under its original location, so just look here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160622041818/http://interactive-matter.eu/how-to/ajson-arduino-json-library/

Answer (score 1):

if you need only one-two easy(out of param) nodes, you can use my function :)

```
String xmlTakeParam(String inStr,String needParam)
{
  if(inStr.indexOf("<"+needParam+">")>0){
     int CountChar=needParam.length();
     int indexStart=inStr.indexOf("<"+needParam+">");
     int indexStop= inStr.indexOf("</"+needParam+">");  
     return inStr.substring(indexStart+CountChar+2, indexStop);
  }
  return "not found";
}
```

I tried to find a solution for a long time, leave it here for clarity.
The complex xml with repeating nodes already so will not succeed.